# What are silent carrier traits?

Tags: genetics, homework, human-genetics

I couldn't find a definition but I have come to know the following from google search:

> People who are carriers of a thalassemia gene show no thalassemia symptoms and might not know they're carriers.

So is thalassemia a "silent carrier trait"?

Comment: How many times do I have to tell you that you should not ask a question about the definition of a term that is not really a standard term? There are no "definitions" for terms like these; they are just contextual and anyone who understands English language would figure out what these terms mean. You did the same in your other question on "[Why is tRNA called an adaptor molecule](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/46416/3340)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thalassemia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalassemia) is a *[recessive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(genetics)) trait*. That means individuals with only one copy of the allele (Heterozygotes) have the "normal" phenotype (they don't have Thalassemia).

If an individual is homozygous for the recessive allele they will have Thalassemia.

Heterozygotes are often referred to as carriers as they can transmit the allele to their offspring, but do not themselves express the trait.

"Silent carrier trait" is quite unusual terminology, just call it a recessive trait.